# How do I replace each element of a series with [element] if a condition is satisfied else []?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, list-comprehension, series

I'm trying to replace each element of the series without having to loop over it, with '[element]' if a condition is satisfied, otherwise [], I need the series to contain list objects in each row in most efficient manner.

I'm able to do this using for loops/list comprehension which is very slow :

```
    def test_method(A_series, B_series)->pd.Series:
        """return type: pd.Series of lists/ a column of lists"""
        C_series = A_series * B_series/ (1+B_series)
        mask_on = (C_series <= A_series *np.exp(-.25)-B_series)
        updated = [[C_series [i]] if (i in set(C_series [mask_on].index)) else [] for i in C_series.index]
        return pd.Series(updated,C_series.index)
```

If the series is as below, and if I give the condition as i%2 ==0, the series should become like on the right side -

```
4     2 -> [2]
12    3 -> []
13    4 -> [4]
15    5 -> []
```

Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
x.where(lambda p: p % 2 == 0, np.nan, inplace=True)

print(x)
#0    0.0
#1    NaN
#2    2.0
#3    NaN
#4    4.0
#5    NaN
#6    6.0
#7    NaN
#8    8.0
#9    NaN
#dtype: float64

x = x.apply(lambda p: [p])
print(x)

#0    [0.0]
#1    [NaN]
#2    [2.0]
#3    [NaN]
#4    [4.0]
#5    [NaN]
#6    [6.0]
#7    [NaN]
#8    [8.0]
#9    [NaN]
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I need an empty list not 'nan' element because I will be using this result elsewhere